# ERROR in ./server.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/server/main.bundle'

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have migrated my agular 5 universal application to angular 6, below are the details of the package, 
Angular CLI: 6.0.7
Node: 8.11.2,

I have followed the, below link to implement angular universal,

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

**Error**  :

```
ERROR in ./server.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/server/main.bundle'
```

Comment: You need to make sure that you run both client and server bundles. Which files do you have in `./dist/server/` ?

Comment: I got the same issue and resolved it and [shared the answer against a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51604995/angular-6-server-side-errror-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-dist-ser/53955077#53955077), Hope it helps you.